# Visual management of main.storyboard objects has disappeared?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

On my previous Mac, when Main.storyboard was selected, I would see a hierarchy of objects like View Controller > Scroll View > Button. I could do things like change the name of a button. That menu has now disappeared after I transferred my project files to my new Mac. However, I can still see the storyboard file. How do I get the menu back? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I'm not sure... in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hIyn_UdFIc) @ 1:28 we see it second to left. It is a hierarchy.

Comment: can you provide me the screenshot of your problem?

Comment: http://imgur.com/lRopGcm sorry for the quality, best I could find for now. I need this panel.

Comment: so you mean button in scrollview not appears in hierarchy...right?

Comment: The picture I sent shows the panel that is not showing up. The Scroll View > Button was just an example of what you could see in this panel.

Comment: in storyboard there is viewcontroller over there?

Comment: No, the entire area in the picture is not showing up. There is nothing there.

Comment: Here is another example image showing the panel that is no longer there. http://i.stack.imgur.com/nnV8x.png